# Angular 2 Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Can any one help to resolve this error i am using angular 2
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts 11:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| };
| import { Component } from '@angular/core';

> import { ViewChild } from ;
>   | /core’;;
>   | /googlemaps’;;

Comment: Please take some effort and reformat your question so it's actually readable by other people than yourself.

Comment: And also take time to explain the problem correctly as we do not  have your code base and have no idea whats going on.

Comment: Kindly give code what you have tried. And What you have to achieve these are things may easy to understand and help to you.

Comment: Also add your app.component.ts file

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts 11:1
Module parse failed: Unterminated regular expression (11:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| };
| import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
> /googlemaps’;;
| var AppComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
|     function AppComponent() {
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.   This is the error what i get actually when add viewchild in app.component.ts file